How to create a theorem box with multiple layers instead of just two
This is what i have so far,

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\NewTotalTColorBox[auto counter]{\Example}{ +m +m }{ 
    notitle,
    colback=blue!5!white,
    colbacklower=white,
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    bicolor,
    sharp corners,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue!50!black},
    fontupper=\sffamily
}{
    \textcolor{blue!50!black}{
        \sffamily
        \textbf{Example~\thetcbcounter.}%
    }%
    #1
    \tcblower%
    \textcolor{blue!50!black}{
    }%
    #2
}

\begin{document}
    \Example{
        Write algebraic expression for the following. Use correct algebraic notation.
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task sum of $x$ and $4$
    \task difference between $2n$ and $10$
    \task $6$ is taken away from $x$
    \task sum of two consecutive integers
\end{tasks} 
    }{
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
$x + 4$

$x - 6$

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
$2n - 10$

$n + (n+1)$
\end{minipage}
    }
\end{document}

But I want to create something like this.

Is it possible?

If you use a tabular inside the box rather than tasks, you could use xcolor to shade the rows of the table.

Not really that great with tables and also, I am numbering examples using a counter so I would have to number examples myself and that would be very confusing to change the numbers every time.

You could easily use a custom counter for the numbering. But maybe somebody else has a better idea.

Here is an implementation modeled on that of the tabulars* and tabulars keys of tcolorbox and using nicematrix to make the colored table. The syntax is
\begin{example}
<text>
\tcblower
<table content>
\end{example}

where the odd-numbered rows are prefixed with the task count, e.g. "a)", and the even-numbered rows are given the correct amount of space to line up with the text above.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\inttoalph}[1]{\int_to_alph:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tcbset{
  NiceTabularX* lower/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=0pt,leftlower=0pt,rightlower=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    before lower*={%
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}%
      \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{#2}[
        rules/color=tcbcolframe,
        code-before=#1,
        ]},
    after lower*={%
      \end{NiceTabularX}
      }
  },
  NiceTabularX lower/.style={NiceTabularX* lower={}{#1}},
}

\newcounter{mytaskcnt}
\renewcommand{\themytaskcnt}{\alph{mytaskcnt}}
\newcommand{\mytask}{%
  \stepcounter{mytaskcnt}%
  \themytaskcnt)\;\;%
  }

\newcounter{example}

\newtcolorbox{example}{
  NiceTabularX* lower={%
    \setcounter{mytaskcnt}{0}%
    \rowcolors{1}{tcbcolback}{white}%
    }{%
    @{\hspace{5mm}}%
    >{\ifodd\value{iRow}\mytask\else\hspace{\widthof{\inttoalph{\value{mytaskcnt}-1})}}\;\;\fi}X%
    >{\ifodd\value{iRow}\mytask\else\hspace{\widthof{\inttoalph{\value{mytaskcnt}})}}\;\;\fi}X%
    @{\hspace{5mm}}%
    },
  before upper*={%
    \refstepcounter{example}
    {\color{blue!50!black}\sffamily\bfseries Example~\theexample.}\:
    },
  colback=blue!5!white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  leftlower=4pt, % so borderline is visible
  borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue!50!black},
  lower separated=false,
  middle=4pt,
  fontupper=\sffamily,
  fontlower=\sffamily,
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  NiceTabularX lower={XX},
  colback=green!20,
  colframe=red
  ]
Write an algebraic expression for the following. Use correct algebraic notation.
\tcblower
sum of $x$ and $4$ & difference between $2n$ and $10$ \\ \hline
$x+4$              & $2n-10$ \\ \hline\hline
$6$ is taken away from $x$ & sum of two consecutive integers \\ \hline
$x - 6$                    & $n + (n+1)$
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{example}
Write an algebraic expression for the following. Use correct algebraic notation.
\tcblower
sum of $x$ and $4$ & difference between $2n$ and $10$ \\
$x+4$              & $2n-10$ \\
$6$ is taken away from $x$ & sum of two consecutive integers \\
$x - 6$                    & $n + (n+1)$
\end{example}

\begin{example}
An excellent problem
\tcblower
bla & bla bla \\
$z$ & $\alpha$
\end{example}

\end{document}


You can customize the tcolorbox options to your liking.
